# Linux shell - Make multiple folders with multiple text files inside them

Tags: linux, directory

I need to make roughly 20 folders (with different names), with multiple text files inside each of them (with different names). eg.

**Folders:** one (two, three, etc.)

**Files (inside folders):** one.txt, two.txt, three.txt etc.

So I should end up with 20 folders, with 2 or more files inside each of those folders.

I thought about using a 'for' loop. But I can't seem to set it up the way that I want.. ex. 'for' only lets me name ALL folders with the same name?

I'll be grateful for any answers.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do a nested `for` loop like this:

```
FOLDERS="one two three four"
FILES="one.txt two.txt three.sh"

for FOLDER in $FOLDERS
do
  mkdir $FOLDER;
  for FILE IN $FILES
  do
    touch ./$FOLDER/$FILE;
  done
done
```

So you can create folders with different files inside. In shell scripting, you can simulate [two-dimensional arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) that maybe is more appropriate to your needs, but I think nested loops will do the trick.

Note: this script will create all the tree of folders and files from your current working directory (you can know it with `pwd`).